# Placeholder in django form dropdown field

Tags: python, django, django-forms, placeholder

I have a little problem with a dropdown field in django form. I want to add to this field placeholder (or not active first option as placeholder) and some other stuff as no label, class etc.
I wrote something like this, in my `forms.py` but now my form is broken - don't save values to database.

```
from .models import Scenario, ScenarioArea
from django import forms

class newScenario(forms.ModelForm):
    scenarioArea=forms.ModelChoiceField(label="", queryset=ScenarioArea.objects.values_list("scenarioAreaName", flat=True).distinct(), empty_label=None)

lass Meta:
        model = Scenario
        fields = ['scenarioArea']
```

Every other field type is working, but not this dropdown...
Could you help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> By default the  widget used by ModelChoiceField will have an
>   empty choice at the top of the list. You can change the text of this
>   label (which is "---------" by default) with the empty_label
>   attribute, or you can disable the empty label entirely by setting
>   empty_label to None:

As you're setting `empty_label` to `None`, this option is not being shown.

**Example**

```
scenario_area = forms.ModelChoiceField(label="", queryset=ScenarioArea.objects.distinct('scenarioAreaName'), empty_label="Placeholder")
```

Comment: Thanks! I used ```scenarioArea = forms.ModelChoiceField(label="", queryset=ScenarioArea.objects.all(), empty_label="Placeholder")``` and it works now!