# Django Model field from foreign key which is displayed with the select tag has empty fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

Hello I have a model in Django where I have a forein key and I am displaying it with a select tag in html. However there are blank options in the selector tag but not in my database. How can I remove them. I want also to ask how I can delete the ------ option.

html, only the select tag

```
<select style='width:200px';name="bolum" required="" id="id_bolum">
                            {% for x in form.bolum %}
                            {% if {{x}} ''%}
                            {%else%}
                            <option value="{{x.id}}">{{x}}</option>
                            {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
</select>
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Department(models.Model):
    department=models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.department

class WPGroup(models.Model):
    bolum = models.ForeignKey('Department', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='department_for_wpgroup',null=False, blank=False)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=128,blank=False)
    number=models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False)
    mail=models.EmailField(max_length=128,blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import WPGroup


class WPGroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=WPGroup
        fields=['name','number','bolum','mail']


    def clean_mail(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['mail']
        if "@itu.edu.tr" not in email:
            raise forms.ValidationError("You must include @itu.edu.tr")
        return email
```

here is also a screenshot of the website

[image]

Comment: You can use the empty_label=None parameter as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59362925/placeholder-in-django-form-dropdown-field

Comment: yes I did but it doesn't worked